# Show/Hide values in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table, show-hide

I have a table structured like that:

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
    <th>Header3</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>some php to get custom field</td>
   <td>also custom field- the loop is above so this is working as it should</td>
   <td>
   <a href="#" class="showhide"> 
    <div class="more">
     .. the content I want to show when user clicks a class="showhide"
    </div>
   </a>
   </td>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to implement with jQuery, but nothing happens. This is the jQuery I tried:

```
$(function () {
    $('.showhide').click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle()
    });
});
```

I also make it with `document.ready` and still not working. Is there any other way to do that?

All I want is that the content of the div class="more" is to be shown under the row in the table (and in front of the next one), of course when the a `class="showhide"` is clicked.

I am using this together with plugin DataTables, but this is not causing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you have is `showmore` not `showhide`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E5X9R/)**

```
$(function() {
  $('.showmore').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle()
  });
});
```

Edit based on OP comments: I have shorten the html to make it simple and took `div` out of `a` tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E5X9R/)**

*Html*

```
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="#" class="showhide"> Show / Hide </a>

                <div class="more">.. the content I want to show when user clicks a class="showmore"</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(function () {
    $('.showhide').click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle()
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry I made I typo when entering the question. Still not working, the problem remains :)

Answer (score 2):

Either change this in the markup:

```
 class="showmore">
```

to this:

```
 class="showhide">
```

or do this:

```
$('.showmore').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().toggle()
});
```

#### Note:

This is invalid html:

```
<a href="#" class="showhide"> 
<div class="more">
 .. the content I want to show when user clicks a class="showhide"
</div>
```

change to this:

```
<a href="#" class="showmore">show more</a> 
<div class="more">
 .. the content I want to show when user clicks a class="showhide"
</div>
```

or you can try this one with `.children()` not with `.next()`:

```
$('.showmore').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('more').toggle();
});
```

#### [TRYOUT IN FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8fF2/)

Comment: sorry, I made a typo when entering question, otherwise the classes are correct and not working

Comment: Brilliant, I only need to put in document ready and switched the other jquery calls. Thanks Jai!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.showmore',function(){
//your code..
})
```